# Bottom Sheet Issue - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error appear to me in bugsnag about the bottom sheet, I don't know where the issue exactly to fix it.

The issue is:

_CastError package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:211

Null check operator used on a null value

errorContext while handling a gesture

errorLibrary gesture

And the code:

showModalBottomSheet( context: context,
isScrollControlled: true, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, builder: (con) => ProductBottomSheetR(),
)

Any advice?

Comment: Can you please share some code

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: edit your question with code